# VBA code required

Tags: vba, excel, compare

VBA Code required for compare two cells in different sheets and if matched then Copy First sheet data into Second sheet (in front of the matched cell) horizontally

Like in Sheet 1

```
Date                Party Name            Amount
23-12-15            Adani                 150000
                    Shree cement          200000
                    Jindal                100000
                    Mittal                50000
```

In Sheet 2

```
01-12-15
05-12-15
10-12-15
20-12-15
23-12-15
```

If sheet 2 data match with sheet 1 (Dates )

Output Required

```
01-12-15
05-12-15
10-12-15
20-12-15
23-12-15  Adani 150000  shree cement 200000  Jindal 100000 Mittal 50000
```

Comment: Does the data in excel look exactly the same way as above?
How many party names can each date have ?

Answer (score 0):

This code will check columns in different sheets and put them in a third sheet. You can modify it to do what you need:

```
dim idx1 as integer
dim idx2 as integer
dim idx3 as integer
idx1 = 2
idx3 = 1
while sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" + Cstr(idx1)).Value <> "" 
    idx2 = 2
    while sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" + Cstr(idx2)).Value <> ""
        if sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" + Cstr(idx1)).Value = sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" + Cstr(idx2)).Value then
            idx3 = idx3 + 1
            sheets("Sheet3").Range("C" + Cstr(idx3)).value = sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" + Cstr(idx1)).Value
        endif
        idx2 = idx2 + 1
    wend
    idx1 = idx1 + 1
wend
```

Comment: Show your code. You need to modify my code to fit your needs. If we see your code we might be able to figure out the problem.